# Is it possible that the length of all diagonals of a convex polygon with perimeter 1 is less than 1/4?

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

I believe that it is impossible that the length of all diagonals of a convex polygon with perimeter 1 is less than 1/4. It is easy to verify the case of quadrilateral: assume the two diagonals are of length $d_1,d_2$, then by trianglular inequality, we have $$2d_1+2d_2\ge 1,$$ so the length of the longer diagonal should be greater than 1/4. Is it true for other convex polygons?

Comment: A triangle has no diagonals, so vacuously they all have length less than $1/4$.

Comment: For any convex body in $\mathbb{R}^2$, its [mean width](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_width) is $\frac{L}{\pi}$ where $L$ is its perimeter. As a corollary, all convex body with parameter $1$ has a pair of point at least at a distance $\frac{1}{\pi}$ apart. For convex $n$-gon, there is a better upper bound but I don't remember what that is...

Comment: How did you achieve 1/4 ? If we consider rhombus and if obtuse angle will go to 180  larger diagonal will try to reach 1/2 , smaller 0.

Comment: @Robert consider $n$-gons with $n\ge 4$.

Comment: Consider an isosceles trapezoid with two vars 0 and 1/2, then diagonals are both 1/4. @AdamWrzesiński

Comment: @achillehui  If you remember something, please let me know. Thank you so much.

Comment: @PcllR My memory failed me but I find something else. For any convex $n$-gon, the $D/P$ ratio is bounded from below by $1/(2n\sin\frac{\pi}{2n})$ and this bound is optimal only for odd $n$. See [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.10618.pdf) and refs there.